# Append new row when using pandas iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have the following code where I create `df['var'2]` and alter `df['var1']`. After performing these changes, I would like to append the `newrow` (with `df['var'2]`)  to the dataframe while keeping the original (though now altered) row (which has `df['var1']`).

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    while row['var1'] > 30: 
        newrow = row
        newrow['var2'] = 30
        row['var1'] = row['var1']-30
        df.append(newrow)
```

I understand that when using `iterrows()`, row variables are copies instead of views which is why the changes are not being updated in the original dataframe. So, how would I alter this code to actually append newrow to the dataframe?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is generally inefficient to append rows to a dataframe in a loop because a new copy is returned.  You are better off storing the intermediate results in a list and then concatenating everything together at the end.

Using `row.loc['var1'] = row['var1'] - 30` will make an inplace change to the original dataframe.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2) * 100, columns=['var1', 'var2'])

>>> df
         var1        var2
0  176.405235   40.015721
1   97.873798  224.089320
2  186.755799  -97.727788
3   95.008842  -15.135721
4  -10.321885   41.059850

new_rows = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    while row['var1'] > 30: 
        newrow = row
        newrow['var2'] = 30
        row.loc['var1'] = row['var1'] - 30
        new_rows.append(newrow.values)
    df_new = df.append(pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns=df.columns)).reset_index()

>>> df
    var1      var2
0  26.405235  30.00000
1   7.873798  30.00000
2   6.755799  30.00000
3   5.008842  30.00000
4 -10.321885  41.05985

>>> df_new
         var1      var2
0   26.405235  30.00000
1    7.873798  30.00000
2    6.755799  30.00000
3    5.008842  30.00000
4  -10.321885  41.05985
5   26.405235  30.00000
6   26.405235  30.00000
7   26.405235  30.00000
8   26.405235  30.00000
9   26.405235  30.00000
10   7.873798  30.00000
11   7.873798  30.00000
12   7.873798  30.00000
13   6.755799  30.00000
14   6.755799  30.00000
15   6.755799  30.00000
16   6.755799  30.00000
17   6.755799  30.00000
18   6.755799  30.00000
19   5.008842  30.00000
20   5.008842  30.00000
21   5.008842  30.00000
```

**EDIT** (per request below):

```
new_rows = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    while row['var1'] > 30: 
        row.loc['var1'] = var1 = row['var1'] - 30
        new_rows.append([var1, 30])
    df_new = df.append(pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns=df.columns)).reset_index()

>>> df_new
    index        var1        var2
0       0   26.405235   40.015721
1       1    7.873798  224.089320
2       2    6.755799  -97.727788
3       3    5.008842  -15.135721
4       4  -10.321885   41.059850
5       0  146.405235   30.000000
6       1  116.405235   30.000000
7       2   86.405235   30.000000
8       3   56.405235   30.000000
9       4   26.405235   30.000000
10      5   67.873798   30.000000
11      6   37.873798   30.000000
12      7    7.873798   30.000000
13      8  156.755799   30.000000
14      9  126.755799   30.000000
15     10   96.755799   30.000000
16     11   66.755799   30.000000
17     12   36.755799   30.000000
18     13    6.755799   30.000000
19     14   65.008842   30.000000
20     15   35.008842   30.000000
21     16    5.008842   30.000000
```

Comment: Hi, @Alexander. Is there a way for me to keep the intermediate values of var1? So, in your example, var1=176, and the df_new has var1=26 six times. How do I get row0: var1=146 var2=30, row2: var1=116 var2=30, etc. Do you know?

Comment: Moving new_rows.append to the line before row.loc['var1']... seemed to have no effect on the output.